# Validating a Date Using Delimiters

Tags: java, validation, date

I currently have the homework task of validating input dates.
The task requires me to: 
• state that the input date is invalid and why it is invalid
e.g. 03 JUL 3062 - INVALID: Year out of range. 
or 
• output a valid date in the following format:
ddyyyy
e.g.
01 Apr 1882 
My teacher would like the format day month year. 
Input may be of any of the following formats: 
day: dd or d or 0d 
month: mm or m or 0m or the first three letters of the month name (all in the same case, or with the first letter upper-case) 
year: yy or yyyy 
separator: - or / or  
Note: only one separator type to be used in one date

I've seen a lot of examples where the month needs to given as an integer but am unsure how to have an input month as "Jan." Any insight whatsoever would be very helpful. Below is the code I currently have:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

    public class Dates{
      public static void main(String[] args){
        //int minYear = 1753, maxYear = 3000;
        int day, month = 0, year = 0;
        int daysInMonth;
        boolean validDay, validMonth, validYear;
        boolean leapYear;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); /*A file or user input?*/
        sc.useDelimiter("/|-|\n"); //how to separate space
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
          String line = sc.nextLine(); //read line into a string
          //find the deliminator

    }

    //check day

    //check month
    leapYear = ((year % 4) == 0 && ((year % 100) != 0) || (year % 400) == 0);
    validMonth = (month >= 1 && month <= 12);

    //check year
    validYear = (year >= 1753 && year <= 3000);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle `String` inputs using `switch`,

```
switch(month){
case "Jan":
  return 1;
case "Feb":
  return 2;
...
case "Dec":
  return 12;
default:
//every other input can be handled here
```